# Грамматика и пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

***Это называется «зрительная галлюцинация», сказал себе Ластик – когда видишь то, чего на самом деле нет*** (Б. Акунин).

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания (тире, отсутствие запятой перед *когда*)? Как определить вид этого предложения?

Comment: Если это прямая речь, то оформлена она неправильно. А если не она, то что?! От этого зависит и отношение к тире/запятой.

Comment: Я думаю, что здесь не классическое, а упрощенное оформление прямой речи (дословного высказывания),  а "сказал себе Ластик" является не словами автора, а вводным предложением. Вот его бы и хотелось обособить с двух сторон.

Comment: Если она "упрощенная", то и пунктуация на совести автора такого "упрощения". Не находите? В нормирующих источниках об этом приеме ничего не сказано.

Comment: Мысли персонажа часто так оформляются, автор здесь не оригинален. Например, сочетание "думаю я" очень часто встречается в виде вводного предложения, например:Зачем он вышел на кровлю, думаю я… А почему бы нет...

Comment: Пунктуация - это раздел грамматики. В титулке плеоназм)))

Comment: Пунктуация - это раздел грамматики?  Не могу согласиться. Грамматика изучает строй языка, в ней  выделяют такие разделы, как словообразование, морфологию (словоизменение) и синтаксис (грамматические конструкции). Пунктуация и орфография - это прикладные науки, они связаны с правильным оформлением письменной речи. Но у нас почему-то грамматику изучают по правилам письма у Розенталя, а это не есть хорошо. Просто у нас правила основаны на грамматике, а  общедоступного грамматического справочника нет. Хотя у того же Розенталя  есть книга "Современный русский язык", где есть грамматический раздел.

Answer (score 1):

Не правильно.

Здесь часть после тире имеет связь с первой частью предложения, поэтому нужна закрывающая запятая (тут явно):

`Это называется «зрительная галлюцинация», сказал себе Ластик, – когда видишь то, чего на самом деле нет. (Б. Акунин)`

Тире очень логично, так как определение понятия (связь). При нём закрывающаяся запятая обязательна.

И мелочь, но автора лучше после точки.

Но больше на прямую речь похоже. Без прямой речи обычно `что` используется.